# WCF: The server method 'MyMethod' failed

Tags: wcf

The WCF service is deployed on different machine.

Im able to get the http://MyServer/MYService.svc/jsdebug file by giving

```
  <identity>
        <dns value="ServerName and the portnumber"/>
```

And I'm able to invoke the service method  using javascript.

After invoking the MyMethod.

I get this error in the javascript --> The server method 'MyMethod' failed, status 404 (in failedCallback)

MyMethod returns a Boolean value in svc.cs file after performing a datacheck.

These are the errors came up when I used Firefox Firebug:

When I call the same service using VS2008 in my development environment it works fine.

I found that following are the files which are not loading while using Ajax enabled VS2005

1) MicrosoftAjax.debug.js(3.5)

2) MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js(3.5) During runtime

Its obvious that 3.5 debug files doesn't load but, 1.0.6 debug files should load without the errors displayed below.

```
 invokeCalledTwice":"Cannot call invoke more than once.",
11"webServiceFailed":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 failed with the following error: {1}",
12"argumentType":"Object cannot be converted to the required type.",
13"argumentNull":"Value cannot be null.",
14"controlCantSetId":"The id property can\u0027t be set on a control.",
15"formatBadFormatSpecifier":"Format specifier was invalid.",
16"webServiceFailedNoMsg":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 failed.",
17"argumentDomElement":"Value must be a DOM element.",
18"invalidExecutorType":"Could not create a valid Sys.Net.WebRequestExecutor from: {0}.",
19"cannotCallBeforeResponse":"Cannot call {0} when responseAvailable is false.",
20"actualValue":"Actual value was {0}.",
21"enumInvalidValue":"\u0027{0}\u0027 is not a valid value for enum {1}.",
22"scriptLoadFailed":"The script \u0027{0}\u0027 could not be loaded.",
23"parameterCount":"Parameter count mismatch.",
24"cannotDeserializeEmptyString":"Cannot deserialize empty string.",
25"formatInvalidString":"Input string was not in a correct format.",
26"invalidTimeout":"Value must be greater than or equal to zero.",
27"cannotAbortBeforeStart":"Cannot abort when executor has not started.",
28"argument":"Value does not fall within the expected range.",
29"cannotDeserializeInvalidJson":"Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.",
30"invalidHttpVerb":"httpVerb cannot be set to an empty or null string.",
31"nullWebRequest":"Cannot call executeRequest with a null webRequest.",
32"eventHandlerInvalid":"Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.",
33"cannotSerializeNonFiniteNumbers":"Cannot serialize non finite numbers.",
34"argumentUndefined":"Value cannot be undefined.",
35"webServiceInvalidReturnType":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 returned an invalid type. Expected type: {1}",
36"servicePathNotSet":"The path to the web service has not been set.",
37"argumentTypeWithTypes":"Object of type \u0027{0}\u0027 cannot be converted to type \u0027{1}\u0027.",
38"cannotCallOnceStarted":"Cannot call {0} once started.",
39"badBaseUrl1":"Base URL does not contain ://.",
40"badBaseUrl2":"Base URL does not contain another /.",
41"badBaseUrl3":"Cannot find last / in base URL.",
42"setExecutorAfterActive":"Cannot set executor after it has become active.",
43"paramName":"Parameter name: {0}",
44"cannotCallOutsideHandler":"Cannot call {0} outside of a completed event handler.",
45"format":"One of the identified items was in an invalid format.",
46"assertFailedCaller":"Assertion Failed: {0}\r\nat {1}",
47"argumentOutOfRange":"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.",
48"webServiceTimedOut":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 timed out.",
49"notImplemented":"The method or operation is not implemented.",
50"assertFailed":"Assertion Failed: {0}",
51"invalidOperation":"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.",
52"breakIntoDebugger":"{0}\r\n\r\nBreak into debugger?"
```

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Do you have Firefox installed?  Might you be able to install Firebug?

Comment: yeh I do have fire bug installed

Comment: I have the WCF call in the page load.

Comment: can you show us how you call the WCF method??

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="Service.svc" />
        </Services>
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Service.js" />
        </Scripts>
        
    </asp:ScriptManager>

and in service.js 

var proxy= new NameSpace.IService();
        proxy.MyMethod(1, varUserName, varDept, OnSuccess, OnFailure);

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you have Firebug installed, you can use it to check the HTTP request and response to see if they contain more information about what went wrong.

Comment: sorry I do not have  Firebug installed on my machine.
I have IE Dev tool bar

Comment: Ok I'm not familiar with that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

These are the errors came up when I used Firefox Firebug:

When I call the same service using VS2008 in my development environment it works fine.

I found that following are the files which are not loading while using Ajax enabled VS2005

1) MicrosoftAjax.debug.js(3.5)

2) MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js(3.5) During runtime

Its obvious that 3.5 debug files doesn't load but, 1.0.6 debug files should load without the errors displayed below.

invokeCalledTwice":"Cannot call invoke more than once.",
11"webServiceFailed":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 failed with the following error: {1}",
12"argumentType":"Object cannot be converted to the required type.",
13"argumentNull":"Value cannot be null.",
14"controlCantSetId":"The id property can\u0027t be set on a control.",
15"formatBadFormatSpecifier":"Format specifier was invalid.",
16"webServiceFailedNoMsg":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 failed.",
17"argumentDomElement":"Value must be a DOM element.",
18"invalidExecutorType":"Could not create a valid Sys.Net.WebRequestExecutor from: {0}.",
19"cannotCallBeforeResponse":"Cannot call {0} when responseAvailable is false.",
20"actualValue":"Actual value was {0}.",
21"enumInvalidValue":"\u0027{0}\u0027 is not a valid value for enum {1}.",
22"scriptLoadFailed":"The script \u0027{0}\u0027 could not be loaded.",
23"parameterCount":"Parameter count mismatch.",
24"cannotDeserializeEmptyString":"Cannot deserialize empty string.",
25"formatInvalidString":"Input string was not in a correct format.",
26"invalidTimeout":"Value must be greater than or equal to zero.",
27"cannotAbortBeforeStart":"Cannot abort when executor has not started.",
28"argument":"Value does not fall within the expected range.",
29"cannotDeserializeInvalidJson":"Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.",
30"invalidHttpVerb":"httpVerb cannot be set to an empty or null string.",
31"nullWebRequest":"Cannot call executeRequest with a null webRequest.",
32"eventHandlerInvalid":"Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.",
33"cannotSerializeNonFiniteNumbers":"Cannot serialize non finite numbers.",
34"argumentUndefined":"Value cannot be undefined.",
35"webServiceInvalidReturnType":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 returned an invalid type. Expected type: {1}",
36"servicePathNotSet":"The path to the web service has not been set.",
37"argumentTypeWithTypes":"Object of type \u0027{0}\u0027 cannot be converted to type \u0027{1}\u0027.",
38"cannotCallOnceStarted":"Cannot call {0} once started.",
39"badBaseUrl1":"Base URL does not contain ://.",
40"badBaseUrl2":"Base URL does not contain another /.",
41"badBaseUrl3":"Cannot find last / in base URL.",
42"setExecutorAfterActive":"Cannot set executor after it has become active.",
43"paramName":"Parameter name: {0}",
44"cannotCallOutsideHandler":"Cannot call {0} outside of a completed event handler.",
45"format":"One of the identified items was in an invalid format.",
46"assertFailedCaller":"Assertion Failed: {0}\r\nat {1}",
47"argumentOutOfRange":"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.",
48"webServiceTimedOut":"The server method \u0027{0}\u0027 timed out.",
49"notImplemented":"The method or operation is not implemented.",
50"assertFailed":"Assertion Failed: {0}",
51"invalidOperation":"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.",
52"breakIntoDebugger":"{0}\r\n\r\nBreak into debugger?"

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of adding a non-answer.

Comment: sorry john I didn't mean that